# number of samples required to estimate mean

Tags: estimation, sampling, mean, statistical-power

I have a dataset consisting of number of times an individual pauses when speaking during a particular recording. I have several recordings per individual (around 10). I ultimately want a measure of the mean number of pauses per given time interval for an individual.

I would like to determine the minimum number of recordings required from which I can calculate a mean which will best approximate the entire dataset (2 samples, 3 samples, 4 samples), or perhaps measure how reliable an approximation a certain number of samples would be (how reliable are 2/3/4 samples as indicators of the whole?).

I'm thinking of it in terms of minimum sample size required to approximate the population, but I'm hopelessly out of my depth when it comes to statistical terminology and techniques.

Could someone give a pointer towards which concepts I should be exploring?

Comment: You’ll always (in some sense) get a tighter estimate by having more samples. How tight of an estimate do you need?

Comment: And the number you need also depends on how variable the samples are. If three recordings give you averages of  3.5, 4.0, 2.9 pauses in a particular time period, that's a lot different from 1.1, 3.2, 6.4.